# Is there a Modern Hebrew chatbot that I can practice with?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, hebrew, writing

An article from 2017 [mentions](https://blog.craftworkz.co/lets-chat-in-hebrew-83183a33f103) that creating a text chatbot in Hebrew is more difficult than for Indo-European languages due to the morphological complexity of Hebrew verbs. The article then proposes a possible solution involving analyzing verbs down to their roots before analyzing a text for meaning.

In the time since this article (or at any time, really), has there been a viable chatbot that one can practice communicating with in basic Modern Hebrew?

I'm not really concerned about the available topics, so either a reflective ELIZA-like bot or a practical question-and-answer bot (e.g. "Please show me a bus schedule for Beersheva to Eliat for August 19, 2020" or "What time does the next bus leave Beersheva for Eliat?") is great.

Comment: Hmm, this is not really a question about language learning, isn't it? More about machine learning.

Comment: @Tsundoku no, the machine learning part was to explain why the question may be non-trivial. The actual question is if there is a Modern Hebrew-speaking chatbot out there that I can practice with in a reasonable way. I edited the title to indicate this. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe chat-gpt ?